# Rails how to use 2 of the same slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates, slug

I am using slugs in my project to give my params an other name but I have two params called: "how-does-it-work". 
(.../investor/how-does-it-work)
(.../customer/how-does-it-work)
I would like to use the slugs as how they are currently set.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two distinct routes/controllers, and simply query the corresponding `ActiveRecord` model in the `show` action. Assuming there is a `slug` field on your models:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :customers
  resources :investors
end

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find_by(slug: params[:id])
  end
end

class InvestorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @investor= Investor.find_by(slug: params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is probably the most conventional way to solve this problem in Rails.   If you are using the friendly_id gem, the same approach more or less applies, except for maybe the query itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, is /investor/ and /customer/ both parts of the slug?

If that's the case, you can split the string, and do a search based on the "how-does-it-work" in the grouping of "investor" or "customer".

If investor and customer are both parts of the routes, you shouldn't have a difficult time there, because they're pointing to two different controller methods. You should be able to write a search based on each of those methods that correspond to the data. If the data is the same, all your doing is pointing the controller to the correct model data with the correct params.

If you're using [friendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slug_generator.rb), it usually has built in candidate matching. Also, if you're meaning to match multiple pages to the same slug (which I've done in the past), you can display a results page if you'd like too, by rendering based on the quantity of results.